# Automatically select a different keyboard layout for a YubiKey

Tags: usb, keyboard-layout

I just got a new [YubiKey](http://www.yubico.com/yubikey) authentication token. Theoretically it works great with Linux as it presents itself to the system as a USB keyboard. However, my default keyboard layout is German Neo, which is radically different from a standard English keyboard. So the passphrase ends up being completely garbage.

Is it possible to automatically have a different keyboard layout applied to the input coming from the YubiKey (the YubiKey identifies itself as `ID 1050:0010 Yubico.com Yubikey` with `lsusb` so I suppose detection should be possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this with udev, there should be sample scripts available in the internet; in the end, you will be calling `setxkbmap -device $n en` where n is the device ID of your secondary keyboard which will probably be a symlink around `/dev/input/by-id/`.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: I'm getting 'Error!   Option "-d" not recognized' message for this command (version 7.5+5).

Comment: From looking at `man setxkbmap`, I think this is supposed to be `-device` instead of `-d`.

Comment: Happens when you post from memory; corrected.

Comment: You can find the device id via `xinput`. Or even `xinput list --short "Yubico Yubico Yubikey II" | cut -f 2 | cut -d = -f 2`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following **how-to** from this [**post**](http://amo-probos.org/post/7).

Just put the mentioned `xorg.conf` snippet into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-yubikey.conf`.

The text to add (from that article) is:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "yubikey"
  MatchIsKeyboard "on"
  MatchVendor     "Yubico"
  MatchProduct    "Yubico Yubikey II"
  Driver          "evdev"
  Option          "XkbRules" "evdev"
  Option          "XkbModel" "pc105"
  Option          "XkbLayout" "us"
  Option          "XkbVariant" "basic"
EndSection
```